Why does Google Play Service for AR doesn't support Redmi K60 Pro(Xiaomi)?)?
To ARCore developers:
I am writing this email to provide feedback on
an issue regarding the AR functionality of the Georgebra 3D Calculator.
I'm using a Redmi K60 Pro phone and found that I can't use the AR feature in the Georgebra 3D calculator.  I checked the list of supported models for Google Play Service for AR, and it includes the K60 and K60 Ultra, but not the K60 Pro.
I think this is a mistake since the K60 Pro has the same or more powerful hardware as the K60 and K60 Ultra and should be able to support AR features as well.
To help you investigate this issue, I'm providing the following information:
Device model: Redmi K60 Pro(Xiaomi)
Android version: 14
Georgebra 3D Calculator Version: 5.2.836.0
I hope you can resolve this issue soon so K60 Pro users can also experience the AR
capabilities of the Georgebra 3D Calculator.
Google Play Service for Ar support Redmi K60 Pro(Xiaomi)

Wrong place for your "e-mail"? For any ARCore specific issue, they have a github repo where you can post your questions. I also see other people asking about the Redmi K60 Pro: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/89#issuecomment-1974819357
I would also suggest to contact the developer of the app you are trying to use.
